# How to install realm as a gradle dependency?

Tags: android, realm

I am completely new to realm. I want to use realm db in my android project. I have gone through the official [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#prerequisites). I need to set up realm in my android project. For that I have added the gradle dependancy as

```
    buildscript {
            repositories {
                     jcenter()
                         }
            dependencies {
                classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"
           }
       }
 apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

This is what they have given in documentation. But this doesn't work for me. It gives error saying `Plugin with id 'realm-android' not found`.

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.db.realmsample"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"
    }
  }

 }

 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
  }
```

Is my configuration correct?

Answer (score 25):

Move the `buildscript` to your main `build.gradle` file (Project) , it shouldn't be there in build.gradle (module:app)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
dependencies {
     classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:<realm version>"
   }
 }
```

This should go to main build.gradle

Comment: From the Realm docs now the latest version is `3.3.1` i.e., `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.3.1"` Ref: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Answer (score 20):

First of all copy the class path dependency to build.gradle file(Project):-

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}
```

Finally, copy and paste the following code on top of build.gradle(App) :-

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Note:- The version 1.2.0 is subjected to change on future releases.For more please check https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: thanks for the link, it is very helpful to know configurations and the last version number!

Comment: @MuSa Android SDK 23

Answer (score 1):

**Prerequisites**

- Android Studio version 1.5.1 or higher
- JDK version 7.0 or higher
- A recent version of the Android SDK
- Android API Level 9 or higher   (Android 2.3 and above)

**Step 1:** Add the class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"
 }
}
```

**Step 2:** Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of the application level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

**Step 3:** Gradle sync

For the official complete installation guide. Please see the following link.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Answer (score 0):

The method I used is

```
   `     dependencies 
{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.4"

    }`
```

in your main  build gradle  file
then add

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

and

```
 compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
```

in your app's build gradle

this link to bintray will give you the latest build 
https://bintray.com/realm/maven/realm-android-library/3.4.0#files/io%2Frealm%2Frealm-android-library%2F3.4.0