# Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.0.0.pre.rc1

Tags: java, android, gradle, realm

I follow the getting start guide for android realm [hear](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/).

I use the newest android studio version 3.0 RC 1 with the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

 repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
 }

 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.0.0.pre.rc1"
 }
}
```

When I sync gradle I receive the following error message:

```
Error:Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.0.0.pre.rc1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/98_Downloads/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-windows/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.0.0.pre.rc1/realm-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pre.rc1.pom
    file:/D:/98_Downloads/android-studio-ide-171.4392136-windows/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.0.0.pre.rc1/realm-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pre.rc1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.0.0.pre.rc1/realm-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pre.rc1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.0.0.pre.rc1/realm-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pre.rc1.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.0.0.pre.rc1/realm-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pre.rc1.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/4.0.0.pre.rc1/realm-gradle-plugin-4.0.0.pre.rc1.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Whats my mistake? Have someone an idea? Thx!

Comment: is gradle android studio in offline mode?

Comment: Can you look this similar helpful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028087/how-to-install-realm-as-a-gradle-dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya it's because the docs are bugged, it's called `4.0.0-RC1`.

It'll get fixed eventually.

---

EDIT: in fact, `4.0.0` is out now as well, see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/